# ReferenceError, spacebars is undefined

Tags: meteor, meteorite, meteor-blaze

Since I updated meteor to 0.8.3 I'm getting following error.

```
ReferenceError: Spacebars is not defined
at Package (packages/compiler/compiler.js:2)
at /home/cis/work/meteor/heber/zzbase-meteor/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/comp

at /home/cis/work/meteor/heber/zzbase-meteor/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/comp

at /home/cis/work/meteor/heber/zzbase-meteor/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:161:1
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/cis/.meteor/tools/cef2bcd356/lib/node_modules/underscore/u

at /home/cis/work/meteor/heber/zzbase-meteor/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
```

I have following packages:

```
accounts-ui , accounts-google, bootstrap-3, email, standard-app-packages, d3, compiler, 
amplify, ace, blaze-layout, iron-router, backbone
```

Please help me, I'm stuck in last 5 days. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem. Ended up doing a new meteor create then did all the required mrt adds... copied the folders there. I saw a post on the Google Group suggesting removing everything in the /packages folder then running mrt update.

Comment: Ohh man, what was the sense I don't know, but I did same copy all files one by one except .meteor and package folder and that is done. Working application, but have some minor issues that I'll fix. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

go to your project dir, and try running `mrt update`

Comment: spacebars should be included with meteor, right. What happens if you add spacebars with: `meteor add spacebars` ?

Comment: I added it, but still not working. I tried with remove blaz-layout use only iron-layout and both vice versa.